# Push Data from Oracle to Microsoft SQL on regular basis

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g

Im new here and i hope i can make my question clear so that you guys can help me with some advise.
Im working with a client who wants to push its data on a regular basis from Oracle to MS SQL 2010 (effectively an ETL).

However, they've asked for a store procedure rather than ETL which was my initial idea.

i've written the store procedure ( almost there) which runs on SQL developer, asks user for input and based on the input parameters display a fact table with list of values and columns.

Now this values need to go into MS SQL Server and this is where i need help. 
Bear in mind, the data in around 50-70,000 rows.

any idea of how best i should take this? I was thinking of creating a connection to MS SQL server in sql developer but i've never done that and I'm struggling there.

any advise is highly appreciated.
thanks

Mo

Answer (score 0):

if stored procedure is your only option, you can [create a linked server to connect to the Oracle server](http://www.sqlburn.com/2014/03/create-linked-server-to-oracle-database.html).  The basic steps:

> Quick summary:
>   1.Install the Oracle client
>   2.Install the tnsnames.ora file
>   3.Restart the SQL Server engine
>   4.Create a linked server

There are actually multiple different ways to do this, it depends on the OS, SQL Server version, Oracle version, and process architecture (32 bit vs 64 bit).  Best thing to do is search the net until you find an article that matches your environment.

Comment: Thanks Greg, SQL server is 2010 and oracle is 11g and both 64 bit. i am not a big fan of store procedure myself, but the client wants it this way....!!

Comment: BTW, can you doublecheck your sql version, i don't believe there is sql 2010.

Comment: thanks a lot. you are right i should've checked, SQL2012 is what i should've said. re stored procedure, should i write my procedure in Oracle or is it easier to do it in MS SQL? silly question, but i assume all the tables have to identical across sql and oracle right?